# Comparing two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I have 2 data frames like following:

```
df1
T_id U_id  U_code  score  
A_0_1 UHJKI XPOS_hp 134
B_1_3 NBVFR LKJ_mm  543
C_9_0 TRFDA NBV_lp  80
D_9_1 KOIUA TRE_po  212
E_0_1 SDFRQ QAS_np  300
E_0_1 SDKIJ JIT_mx  160
F_0_1 JKOPA TOZ_po  79

df2
T_id U_id  U_code  score
A_0_1 UHJKI XPOS_hp 150
B_1_3 NBVFR LKJ_mm  520
C_9_0 TRFDG NBJ_po  90
D_9_1 KOIUA TRE_po  250
E_0_1 SDFRQ QAS_np  300
E_0_1 SDKIJ JIT_mx  160
F_0_1 LOLPO JUZ_ic  90
```

I would like to compare the score of df1 and df2 for those entries in df1 which has exactly the same `T_id, U_id and U_code`in df2 and classify them into 3 groups based on the conditions (`df1$score >df2$score, df1$score=df2$score, df$1score<df2score`) like following:

```
df$1score=df2$score
E_0_1 SDFRQ QAS_np  300
E_0_1 SDKIJ JIT_mx  160
df1$score > df2$score
B_1_3 NBVFR LKJ_mm  543
df1$score < df2$score
A_0_1 UHJKI XPOS_hp 150
D_9_1 KOIUA TRE_po  250
```

Also I would like store the entries of df1 for which no match found in df2

```
No matches
C_9_0 TRFDA NBV_lp  80
F_0_1 JKOPA TOZ_po  79
```

I tried the following R code

```
comparison=function(df1,df2)
{
df1_equal_df2=NULL
df1_greater_than_df2=NULL
df1_smaller_than_df2=NULL
no_match=NULL
if(df$T_id==df2$T_id && df1$U_id == df2$U_id && df1$U_code==df2$U_code && df1$score > df2$score)
 {
   df1_greater_than_df2=df$T_id
 }
else if(df$T_id==df2$T_id && df1$U_id == df2$U_id && df1$U_code==df2$U_code && df1$score < df2$score)
 {
   df1_smaller_than_df2=df1$id
 }
else if(df$T_id==df2$T_id && df1$U_id == df2$U_id && df1$U_code==df2$U_code && df1$score = df2$score)
  {
     df1_equal_df2=df$1
  }
else
  {
     no_match=df$1
  }

}
```

But the above didnt work. How can I get my desired output. Kindly guide me

Comment: Why not merge your data first? Then all other operations are easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by=c("T_id","U_id","U_code")) %>%
               mutate(comp=ifelse(score.x > score.y,"df1$score > df2$score",ifelse(score.x < score.y,"df1$score < df2$score","df1$score == df2$score"))) %>%
               rename(score=score.x) %>% select(-score.y)
##   T_id  U_id  U_code score                   comp
##1 A_0_1 UHJKI XPOS_hp   134  df1$score < df2$score
##2 B_1_3 NBVFR  LKJ_mm   543  df1$score > df2$score
##3 C_9_0 TRFDA  NBV_lp    80                   <NA>
##4 D_9_1 KOIUA  TRE_po   212  df1$score < df2$score
##5 E_0_1 SDFRQ  QAS_np   300 df1$score == df2$score
##6 E_0_1 SDKIJ  JIT_mx   160 df1$score == df2$score
##7 F_0_1 JKOPA  TOZ_po    79                   <NA>
```

We perform a left outer join of `df1` and `df2` by `T_id, U_id, and U_code`. This will merge the two tables where the `score` from `df1` is `score.x` and the `score` from `df2` is `score.y`. Then use `mutate` to create the column `comp` that denotes whether `score.x` is greater than, less than, or equal to `score.y`. Finally, we rename the `score.x` column to `score` and remove the `score.y` column to make the result cleaner for presentation.

An equivalent implementation using base-R is:

```
res <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("T_id","U_id","U_code"), all.x=TRUE)
res$comp <- ifelse(res$score.x > res$score.y,"df1$score > df2$score",ifelse(res$score.x < res$score.y,"df1$score < df2$score","df1$score == df2$score"))
res <- res[,c(1:4,6)]
colnames(res) <- sub("score.x","score",colnames(res))
```

which gives the same result. If you then wish to `split` this resulting data frame by `comp`:

```
split(res[,-5],res$comp)
##$`df1$score < df2$score`
##   T_id  U_id  U_code score
##1 A_0_1 UHJKI XPOS_hp   134
##4 D_9_1 KOIUA  TRE_po   212
##
##$`df1$score == df2$score`
##   T_id  U_id U_code score
##5 E_0_1 SDFRQ QAS_np   300
##6 E_0_1 SDKIJ JIT_mx   160
##
##$`df1$score > df2$score`
##   T_id  U_id U_code score
##2 B_1_3 NBVFR LKJ_mm   543
```